# How to use key up in <tag-input> tag in angular2

Tags: angular

Mytemplate,

```
    <tag-input (keyup)="searchfortags(tag.value)" #tag >
</tag-input>
```

my ts,

```
searchfortags(tag:ITag){
    console.log(tag)
}

console:Undefined

ITags{
tag:string;
}
```

With these keyup,i am getting the value as undefined in console.Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you try to accomplish

```
<tag-input (keyup)="searchfortags($event)">
```

or

```
<tag-input (change)="searchfortags(tag.value)" #tag >
```

or

```
<tag-input (ngModelChange)="searchfortags($event)">
```

Comment: with <tag-input (keyup)="searchfortags($event)"> this i am getting    [object%20KeyboardEvent] and the remaing 2 cases are not wrkng

Comment: What would "working" look like? Sorry, missed the `tag-` in `tag-input` I assumed `<input>`